# Angular 2- change class from one component to another

Tags: angular

I have 2 components- A,B
And want from A change B's class.for example change ng-valid to ng-invalid

`<A  #a></A >
<B> </B>`

From B I want give class to A,or change A's ng-valid class to ng-invalid.

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more?

Comment: Hi,I updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this plunker to get an idea of how to do it: https://plnkr.co/edit/wz771Lnnn3GjHWFmykGl?p=preview

As you commented, you could use an `@Input` to get access to that component..

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'AComp',
  template: 'a-component',
  styles: [
    ':host(.ng-valid) { color: green; font-weight: bold; }',
    ':host(.ng-invalid) { color: red; font-weight: bold; }'
    ]
})
export class AComp {

  constructor(private _eRef: ElementRef) {}

  public addClass(c: string) {
    console.dir(this._eRef);
    this._eRef.nativeElement.classList.add(c);
  }

  public removeClass(c: string) {
    this._eRef.nativeElement.classList.remove(c);
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'BComp',
  template: 'b-component'
})
export class BComp {

  @Input('a-comp') private _aComp: AComp;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._aComp.addClass('ng-valid')
    setTimeout(() => this._aComp.addClass('ng-invalid'), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => this._aComp.removeClass('ng-invalid'), 3000);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <AComp #acmp></AComp>
      <br />
      <BComp [a-comp]="acmp"></BComp>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, AComp, BComp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: thank you for answer,One question-You are change BComp class in BComp -`[class.anyClassNameHere]="acmp.booleanValueToTriggerAClass"`.

I want access from AComp to BComp class,and change its class from AComp.?Is it possible?

Comment: thank you dear @mxii,its works.yes it's better for my case. 
and last question-can we all logic move in BComp,i.e
` [class.ng-valid]="bcmp.booleanValueToTriggerAClass"
        [class.ng-invalid]="!bcmp.booleanValueToTriggerAClass"`
dont write in AComp,the Acomp pass as Input to  BComp and,in BComp change AComp classes.